# Not a problem yet

Tags: internet

I'm not having a problem yet but I read the questions forum everyday as I'm new to Linux and it seems a lot of people having trouble with wifi connection. I have a hp Stream 11 and I have installed 16.04 LTS on it. My Wifi connection works fine or at least so far it does. If I do get problem with the wifi where do I find the solution. I have only one computer and I use it for studies. Just want to be prepared!

Comment: If you do not have a problem, do not post a question. If you have an answer to any of the questions you see here, please answer them ;)

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to AskUbuntu!

If your wifi works after installing Ubuntu, then there there is nothing to worry about and no need to fret. 16.04 is very stable at this point, so no changes will be made that could break your wifi driver.

If you ever *do* have a problem, we'll be here for support. But you'll be fine at least until the next big version upgrade :)

Enjoy your new operating system!